# Xamarin find the viewcell that has my object as a datacontext

Tags: listview, xamarin

I have a ListView that is populated via dataBinding and it's viewCells get templated via DataTemplateSelector.

my ListView looks like this :

```
<ListView x:Name="PuzzlesContainer"
          ItemsSource="{x:Static gameBrain:GameItems.Puzzles}"
          RowHeight="167"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PuzzleDataTemplateSelector}"/>
```

Then at some point I will get a modification in one Puzzle that needs to be represented with lines drawn in a canvas that's on its viewCell (from the DataTemplate)

How can I access the ViewCell that has my puzzle as a DataContext to be able to update manually the Canvas ??

Comment: why would you want to manage that manually? why not raise change notification and have the datatemplate take care of it?

Comment: imagine I have a map with points and I need to draw lines from point to point when the system tell's me that the user is moving. How do I draw this to a cavnas using a ValueConverter ???

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom control derived from ViewCell to you inside your list. In xaml You'll have a template, in code-behide you will set value without binding xaml to data. It will update faster. In theory you wont need templateselector as in code-behind you can do everything with you cell now.
Your cell class:

```
            private INotifyPropertyChanged _oldBindingContext;

//this normally fires when you set your list ItemsSource
            protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
            {
                if (_oldBindingContext != null)
                {
                    _oldBindingContext.PropertyChanged -= OnBindingContextPropertyChanged;
                }

                if (BindingContext != null)
                {
                    INotifyPropertyChanged ctx = null;
                    try
                    {
                        ctx = (INotifyPropertyChanged)BindingContext;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
                        return;
                    }
                    ctx.PropertyChanged += OnBindingContextPropertyChanged;
                }
                _oldBindingContext = (INotifyPropertyChanged)BindingContext;
                OnCellBindingContextChanged();
                base.OnBindingContextChanged();
            }

            public virtual void OnCellBindingContextChanged()
            {
            if (BindingContext == null) return;

            //update your xaml here.

            var model = (MyItemCLass)BindingContext;
            MyXamlTextBox.Text = model.Title;


            }

    //you are left with the challenge to call dispose manually when your page destroys. 
    //im calling this from my custom list for every cell when page pops up
            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (BindingContext != null)
                {
                    INotifyPropertyChanged ctx = null;
                    try
                    {
                        ctx = (INotifyPropertyChanged)BindingContext;
                        ctx.PropertyChanged -= OnBindingContextPropertyChanged;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }           
            }

            //and this is what your question is about:
            //when a single property of your model changes we land here to react
            private void OnBindingContextPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {                        
                if (e== null || BindingContext==null) return;
    var = PropertyName = e?.PropertyName;
    //todo more checks

                var propertyInfo = BindingContext.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                if (propertyInfo == null) return;

                if (propertyName == "IsFavorite")
                {
                    UpdateFav((MySupaItem)BindingContext);
                }

    }
```

Comment: I have the impresion that bindingContextChanged onli fires if I change the binding context, not everytime one property of my binded element changes. Am I wrong ?

Comment: you are right, as i wrote after that "cells can receive an appropriate message, or attach itself to some eventhandler". if you need some sample code pls let me know

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Comment: my problem is actually finding what you call "MyXamlTextBox" I have a listview tant gets filled with items from a datatemplate so I have lots of labels with no name. What I need is a reference to the viewcell containing the labels of THIS particular item. How can I get it ??

Comment: If you subclass a viewcell in its code-behind 'this' is your reference to any particular viewcell.